# Use SSL for logstash-output-stomp

Tags: ssl, plugins, logstash, stomp

This is my part of `logstash.conf`:

```
output {
    stomp {
        host => "localhost"
        port => "61613"
        destination => "/queue/test"
        user => "admin"
        password => "admin"
        headers => {
            "persistent" => true
        }
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Now I want send message to ActiveMQ with SSL. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this PR](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-stomp/pull/20) from the logstash-plugins project it appears that SSL/TLS is not supported with Stomp.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, https://github.com/kfogle/logstash-output-stomp. After hard searches, I find that this fork is supported SSL/TLS.